# Disable WAL writes for no effect updates in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgres server where the WAL log often becomes the bottlenect. The reason for this is that we every x minutes sync part of the database with biqQuery schema. I perform this syncing by inserting all the data into a temporary table and then upserting the parent table with the temporary table. I got heavy WAL log blocks, so I changed the query to only upsert if there was not an existing match. Which solved the problem. But it also made me wonder is there a postgres setting to make postgres check if an update has no effect before writing it to WAL? In the same manner as there is a setting to do it for triggers.

My expected output is that:

```
UPDATE my_table set my_column = 'test';
```

Triggers no WAL logs if `my_column = 'test'` for all rows.

Comment: Add `WHERE my_column <> 'test'` to your query

Comment: The points to not have to write this. Allot of the queries are much much more advanced than this and we are multiple developers that forget stuff. So as the question specifies it is about a setting, your suggestion is allready implimented.

Comment: `developers that forget stuff.` that's a much bigger problem and this can't be resolved by some magical configuration setting. Code reviews, testing, education, that kind of things are needed to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The king's way is to not perform an unnecessary update, for example by adding a `WHERE` condition that makes sure that something has changed.

The next best solution is to create a `BEFORE` trigger using the trigger function [`suppress_redundant_updates_trigger()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-trigger.html#BUILTIN-TRIGGERS-TABLE), which will suppress such updates.

Comment: Just wondering if there was a suppress_redundant_wal_writes or something similar?

Comment: No. I would have told you if there was.